# Collecting values of certain searches using selector

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors

Running my script written in python I can get names flawlessly. However, in case of phones and addresses I get "ph." and "Email" as result just like below instead of it's value. How can i get the value of "ph." and "Email" using selector.

Results I'm having like:

```
arkLAB Architecture Ph. Email
Conrad Gargett Ph. Email
MONDO ARCHITECTS Ph. Email
```

The script I'm trying to get the result with:

```
import requests 
from lxml import html

main_url = "http://www.findanarchitect.com.au/index.php"

def get_content(link):

    payload = {'action':'show_search_result','action_spam':'dDfgEr','txtSearchType':5,'txtPracName':'','optSstate':3,'optRegions':23,'txtPcode':'','txtShowBuildingType':0,'optBuildingType':1,'optHomeType':1,'optBudget':''}
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36'}
    tree = html.fromstring(requests.post(link, data = payload, headers = headers).text)

    for title in tree.cssselect("div#searchresultaplus"):
        names = title.cssselect("h2")[0].text
        phone = title.cssselect("div p > strong:contains('ph.')")[0].text
        email = title.cssselect("div p > strong:contains('Email')")[0].text
        print(names, phone, email)

get_content(main_url)
```

Elements in which the value are located:

```
<div id="searchresultsapluscont">    
        <h2>Hugh Gordon Architect P/L</h2>
            <div id="archdetails">
            <div style="float:left">
                <p>
                    Unit 5/6 Lonsdale Street <br>
                    BRADDON ACT 2612
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Ph.</strong> 02 6253 4448<br>
                     <strong>Email</strong> info@hughgordon.com.au
                </p>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right" class="yogi_v"><div class="img_box">
    <img src="/img/aplusprofile.png" alt="aplus logo">
</div></div>    
            <div class="clearboth">
                        <div><img src="/img/fe_img/resultline.png"></div>
            <p><br>Our company has been designing homes, apartments &amp; townhouses for the past two decades in the A.C.T. and N.S.W. This experience has allowed us to become a leading architecture firm, with great focus on the Multi-Residential sector. Due to our diverse team of designers, town planners, lawyers and Architects we are able to provide sophisticated and complex design solutions for all sectors of the Built Environment. With our head office based in Canberra, A.C.T. we are centrally located and conveniently placed to service both the Sydney, South Coast and Victorian regions.</p></div>

        </div>
        <div style="float:right">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="js_show_profile('3796')"><img src="/files/profile_img/3796/4342_4_preview.jpg" alt="Feature Image"></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="clearboth">
            <div style="float:left;"><input type="image" src="/img/fe_img/btn_profileaplus.png" value="View profile" onclick="return js_show_profile('3796')" class="nopad">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="float:left;"><input type="image" src="/img/fe_img/btn_awardsaplus.png" value="Awards" onclick="return js_show_awards('3796')" class="nopad">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="idFavBtn_3796" style="padding-top:1px;"><a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="js_addto_fav('3796','Hugh Gordon Architect P/L','1')"><img src="/img/addtofavaplus.png"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Btw, I don't wish to go for xpath here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The current state of CSS can't do this.

The problem here is that the content you write to the screen doesn't show up in the DOM, try to use ::outside

Comment: Would you be little explicit about what you meant by "use ::outside"? Forgive for my ignorance.

Comment: like this: p::outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tail` attribute.  It contains the text that directly follows the element, up to the next element.

```
names = title.cssselect("h2")[0].text
phone = title.cssselect("div p > strong:contains('ph.')")[0].tail.strip()
email = title.cssselect("div p > strong:contains('Email')")[0].tail.strip()
```

Comment: No way!! This is none other than sir t.m.adam, whose solution never goes astray. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sir t.m.adam, you might take a look at the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836692/grabbing-items-using-selector-within-python-script