# Grabbing items using selector within python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors

I've written some code in python to get company details and names from a webpage. I used css selector in my script to collect those items. However, when I run it I get "company details" and "contact" only the first portion separated by "br" tag out of a full string. How can i get the full portion other than what I've got?

Script I'm trying with:

```
import requests ; from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring(requests.get("https://www.austrade.gov.au/SupplierDetails.aspx?ORGID=ORG8000000314&folderid=1736").text)
for title in tree.cssselect("div.contact-details"):
    cDetails = title.cssselect("h3:contains('Contact Details')+p")[0].text
    cContact = title.cssselect("h4:contains('Contact')+p")[0].text
    print(cDetails, cContact)
```

Elements within which the search results are:

```
<div class="contact-details block dark">
                <h3>Contact Details</h3><p>Company Name: Distance Learning Australia Pty Ltd<br>Phone: +61 2 6262 2964<br>Fax: +61 2 6169 3168<br>Email: <a href="mailto:rto@dla.com.au">rto@dla.com.au</a><br>Web: <a target="_blank" href="http://dla.edu.au">http://dla.edu.au</a></p><h4>Address</h4><p>Suite 108A, 49 Phillip Avenue<br>Watson<br>ACT<br>2602</p><h4>Contact</h4><p>Name: Christine Jarrett<br>Phone: +61 2 6262 2964<br>Fax: +61 2 6169 3168<br>Email: <a href="mailto:chris.jarrett@dla.com.au">chris.jarrett@dla.com.au</a></p>
            </div>
```

Results I'm getting:

```
Company Name: Distance Learning Australia Pty Ltd Name: Christine Jarrett
```

Results I'm after:

```
Company Name: Distance Learning Australia Pty Ltd
Phone: +61 2 6262 2964
Fax: +61 2 6169 3168
Email: rto@dla.com.au

Name: Christine Jarrett
Phone: +61 2 6262 2964
Fax: +61 2 6169 3168
Email: chris.jarrett@dla.com.au
```

Btw, my intention is to do the aforesaid thing using selectors only, not xpath. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace `text` property with `text_content()` method as below to get required output:

```
cDetails = title.cssselect("h3:contains('Contact Details')+p")[0].text_content()
cContact = title.cssselect("h4:contains('Contact')+p")[0].text_content()
```

Comment: One thing to know outside this context, sir Andersson. Why cant I use "::after" or "::before" in my selector cause If I attempt to do any I get an error "Pseudo-elements are not supported." However, I found this in a documentation on css selector. Is there any version related conflict?

Comment: You cannot locate pseudo-elements as they are not part of DOM. They can be used in CSS selectors to set some styles in HTML source code, but not for web-scraping

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`text` returns first text node. If you want to iterate over all child nodes while grabbing text nodes use `xpath` like:

```
company_details = title.cssselect("h3:contains('Contact Details')+p")[0]
for node in company_details.xpath("child::node()"):
    print node
```

result:

```
Company Name: Distance Learning Australia Pty Ltd
<Element br at 0x7f625419eaa0>
Phone: +61 2 6262 2964
<Element br at 0x7f625419ed08>
Fax: +61 2 6169 3168
<Element br at 0x7f625419e940>
Email: 
<Element a at 0x7f625419e8e8>
<Element br at 0x7f625419eba8>
Web: 
<Element a at 0x7f6254155af8>
```